# Error occurred: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Google App Password on docker failing and on dev working

Tags: docker, email, gmail, nodemailer

I have created an app password on Google and stored also in the .env files:

```
EMAIL_SERVICE=gmail
EMAIL_USERNAME=emailtest@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD="xxxx yyyy zzzz cccc"
```

This is the code:

```
const sendEmailResetPassword = async (
  email,
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create a transporter object using Gmail SMTP transport
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    // Define the email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
    };

    // Send the email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error occurred:", error.message);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(info);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

When I run the service locally with `npm run dev`, I do not get any error and the email is sent successfully.

When I build the image and run the docker container, it fails, I know the .env is recognized because I checked using

```
docker exec -it container env
```

And it prints:

```
EMAIL_SERVICE=gmail
EMAIL_USERNAME=emailtest@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD="xxxx yyyy zzzz cccc"
```

When I send when I run the docker container, I get this:

```
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials fl25-20020a05600c0b9900b0040b3e26872dsm28169818wmb.8 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
```

Also, the other .env variables are working such as MySQL URL and others so the .env variables are recognized and are functional.

Comment: Do you have spaces in the apps password?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Yes there are, used parentheses, for  example
"AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD" because google generates like that.

Comment: Remove them you don't need the spaces

Comment: I will see about mentioning it to the team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password generated by Google is something like this:
`"AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD"`, I removed the spaces removed the parenthesis so it looked like this:
`AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD` and it worked.